# If clause in regular Python for-loop

Tags: python

Is it possible to basically do the following in Python:

```
for elem in my_list if elem:
    #Do something with elem...
```

Note that I want to specifically avoid using map, lambdas, or filter to create a second list that gives the Boolean condition, and I don't want to do the following:

```
for elem in [item for item in my_list if item]:
    #Do something...
```

The latter method requires the construction of the Boolean list too. In my code, my_list can be very, very large.

Basically, the simplest way would be to write

```
for elem in my_list:
    if elem:
        #Do stuff...
```

but I specifically want this all in one line. If all-in-one-line won't make the code actually any different than this last example I gave, that's fine too and I will go with that.

Comment: Define "do something with elem".

Comment: That shouldn't be relevant. Just any normal body of a for-loop. We could just use `print elem` as an example, but it's not relevant. Assume I want to print all of the non-empty strings in `my_list` using only one single conditional statement and only one pass through my_list **without** forming a new list that contains only the non-empty strings from `my_list`.

Comment: It's relevant for the reason that you can often reasonably refactor the whole thing into a list comprehension. That wouldn't seem to make sense for printing, until you realise that you can do something like `print '\n'.join(item for item in my_list if item != '')`.

Comment: `if not (elem=='')` is equivalent to `if elem` assuming they're all strings.

Comment: @agf Thanks, I updated. I was aware, but it's probably good so that others don't all point that out too.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was trying to specifically avoid list comprehensions because they have to form the result list. I want each element that would be in the list comprehension output, but one at a time without ever needing to all be in a new list at once. As it turns out, I do need to do more than just print, but even if I just wanted to print, your list comprehension would not be as memory efficient as a plain for...if.. nested conditional that would not be making a whole new list before printing.

Comment: ... So, as suggested (and as in my actual example), use a generator expression rather than a list comprehension. :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) instead of a list comprehension.

```
for elem in (item for item in my_list if not (item=='')):
    #Do something...
```

Comment: When the documentation says this is evaluated "lazily" does this mean the generator expression won't go and get the next value of `item` until the `for elem` part requests it?

Comment: Yes. The next value will only be evaluated when for needs it.

Comment: @EMS: For example: `a = range(3); g = ((x, y) for x in a for y in b)`. Initially 'a' has to exist but not 'b'. The iterator for 'b' is evaluated after `next(g)` triggers the nested loop.

Comment: Thank you guys for the concise answers and for further explaining the generators. I think other answers/comments assumed I was not competent or something... I've used list comprehensions a ton, just never had heard of generators to avoid creating the whole returned list.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `ifilter()` function in `itertools`.

Comment: Specifically `ifilter(None, my_list)` in this case.

Comment: It appears that since `ifilter` uses `yield`, it is also a generator expression, so is it correct that it doesn't return the whole list, just the elements as they are requested?

Comment: @EMS `ifilter` doesn't actually use `yield`, it's implemented in C. But yes, _all_ of `itertools` works like that; it's the entire point of the module.

Comment: The [documentation for `ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) says that it does use yield.